# Loading more than one Blender-exported object/mesh+material in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, uv-mapping

I've modelled two objects in [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), with different materials and different textures UV-mapped to them. I'm rendering it with the [CanvasRenderer](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/49/#CanvasRenderer)

If I [export it](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender), there is more than one material but just one mesh in the resulting [JSON file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.0).

This is the (simplified) code I use to load a model with Three.js:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(myModelPath, function {

    var material = geometry.materials[0];
    material.morphTargets = true;
    material.overdraw = true;

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    scene.add(mesh);

});
```

As you can see, I'm only using the `[0]` material. The result is that the second object uses the first object's material (if I use the `[1]` material, the opposite happens).

But I do not know how to create a mesh that uses more than one material!

Is it even possible? Or, is there a way to export more than one JSON file from Blender (one per object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have probably made improvements to the json exporter since this question was asked, but it is possible now. In the export options near the bottom under settings, there is a checkbox for all meshes. Uncheck that and only the selected mesh will be exported.

Comment: Oooh, that's good to hear! I'm not going to check if it works but assuming it does, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for sharing the info.

Answer (score 3):

You know what? There is a relatively easy way of going about a case like this.

1. Model in blender as usual.
2. <kbd>Save as copy</kbd> as many copies as objects you have.
3. Open each copy, and *delete everything except the pertinent object*.
   Now you have `obj1.blend`, `obj2.blend`, etc.
4. In each of these, export to three.js as you go.
5. Load them all. In my code, this is as simple as adding strings to an array.

Note that if there's a more straight-forward way of going about it, I'd like to know too :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the THREE.ObjLoader. In the blender export settings you can select scene and materials at the bottom of the export options. Voila